# A an nxn matrix. P a permutation matrix that permutes columns of A. How many operations does P*A involve?

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, matrices

Essentially, I am supposed to count how many operations a particular computational algorithm involves, and I've gotten stuck on this one part. My understanding is that for two nxn matrices, matrix multiplication requires of order $0(n^3)$ operations.

If P is a permutation matrix, and we also know the particular permutation that it represents, how many operations does P*A involve?

I'm assuming that it's of order $0(n)$? Or maybe even none (say, if the permutation simply involves storing the values differently - switching which values are in which columns)?

Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an $n \times 1$ vector $v$ and $n \times n$ matrix $A$, to get the first entry of the resulting vector $Av$ you require $n$ multiplications and $n-1$ additions. Doing this for each ot the $n$ rows (entries), you get $n(n+n-1) \sim O(n^2)$ operations. Matrix multiplication is just $Av$ done for each of the $n$ columns $v$ of the second matrix, so the resulting operation count is $O(n^3)$, as you said.

However, in your case, multiplying on the left by $P$ corresponds to permuting the rows of $A$. In other words, if $P$ represents the permutation $\sigma \in S_n$, $\sigma : \{1,\dots,n\} \rightarrow \{1,\dots,n\}$, then the resulting matrix $PA$ has entries $a(\sigma(i),j)$, where $a(i,j)$ is the $i,j$ entry of $A$. Depending on the language you are using and how you code this, this should take no time at all.

Comment: Thanks! One more question.. is it not possible to permute columns with premultiplication? or will P need to be a post-multiplying matrix?

Comment: I do not see how it would be possible to have $PA$ permute the columns. As you say, you will have to use $AP$. The simplest way to convince yourself is by trying $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: You're right, I see it now. Thanks :)